# Why is my Applescript opening multiple terminal windows?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to write a script that will open Sublime Text in my working directory, cd to my VM folder and execute "vagrant up", then open my site directory in chrome.

The script works, just not well. It opens three terminal windows and, on occasion, multiple Sublime windows. Any thoughts or ideas? Also, how would I go about having Chrome open the URL in the new tab that is automatically created on opening rather than making a second new tab?

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "http://codeup.dev"
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "subl ~/vagrant-lamp/sites/codeup.dev/public/"
    do script "cd ~/vagrant-lamp/; vagrant up"
end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `do script` without specifying a location opens always a new window.
Add a `window` or a `tab` with the `in` parameter

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "subl ~/vagrant-lamp/sites/codeup.dev/public/" in window 1
    do script "cd ~/vagrant-lamp/; vagrant up" in window 1
end tell
```

I don't have Chrome but I guess there is a similar terminology.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I overlooked that! I'm still not sure what's going on with Sublime Text though. Maybe its a setting that opens windows on relaunch. As for Chrome, I'll post that specific part of the script in a new question and try my luck.

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent an error from occurring when Terminal does not have an open window.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    do script "subl ~/vagrant-lamp/sites/codeup.dev/public/" in window 1
    do script "cd ~/vagrant-lamp/; vagrant up" in window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for the error catch. I actually never ran into a problem with Terminal throwing an error if it wasn't open, but its nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Chrome: If you move the open location statement to one line and you had no open open Chrome windows before, Chrome will only open the tab you pass to it:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to open location "http://codeup.dev"
```

Regarding the multiple Terminal windows, vadian's answer is correct. I'd like to point out that there is a way to run shell scripts via AppleScript without launching Terminal. This may be helpful: `do shell script` [Here is Apple's documentation on it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html)